# Grails 1.2.x scripts not working

Tags: groovy, grails

I am using Grails 1.2.x (Tried both 1.2.0 and 1.2.2- same behavior)

I am able to create the application fine by using the command grails create-app

But, when I try any command within the project- it "freezes" after printing the Base Directory

I have tried grails clean, grails war, grails run-app, grails created-domain-class

Grails 1.1.x works just fine for me

UPDATE : 1.2-M2 worked as well. but not the other "stable" Grails 1.2.x releases

Any help would be welcome

> C:\mylab\testhostc>grails war
>
> Welcome to Grails 1.2.0 - http://grails.org/
>
> Licensed under Apache Standard License2.0
>
> Grails home is set to: C:\Programs\grails-1.2.0
>
> Base Directory: C:\mylab\testhostc

Comment: Check your JAVA_HOME as well. 

Also if you "SET DEBUG=true" from the command line, and then run "groovy clean", you'll see a whole lot of debugging info that can help you out.

Comment: Tried that. It did print lots of information before it came to the point where it freezes.
I also compared the information generated for 1.1.1 with 1.2.2 and as far as i can see- its same for both except the obvious changes in paths.
So still stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working now

I had an environment variable JAVA_OPTS with value as -Xms64M -Xmx128M -Xss128M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M

Once I removed that- the scripts work fine now

I have opened a defect for this- in case someone is interested

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-6111